# Difference between HTML template content and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

Say I have an HTML `<template>` tag that I define and select as follows:

```
<template>
  <h1>This is my template</h1>
</template>

let myTemplate = document.querySelector('template')
```

What is the difference between these properties of the template:

```
myTemplate.content

myTemplate.innerHTML
```

Comment: The first returns a document fragment, the second a string. Is there something more you are asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to `innerHTML`, `content` returns a document fragment, and so you get immediate access to the DOM without an intermediate conversion to and from a string.

Here is the difference in use:

```js
let myTemplate = document.querySelector('template');

// Method 1
let myDiv1 = document.getElementById('div1');
myDiv1.innerHTML = myTemplate.innerHTML;

// Method 2
let myDiv2 = document.getElementById('div2');
myDiv2.appendChild(myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<template>
  <h3>This is my template</h3>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</template>

<div id="div1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Note that ``.content`` will remove the template content from the Template, because the content is moved. So if you had reversed method 1 and 2 the call for innerHTML would be empty. To re-use you need to do ``*.append(myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true))``  (appendChild only required when you want a reference)

Comment: Yes, that is good remark. I updated the code so that the template retains its contents.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman : `myTemplate.content` does not seem to remove the content. In fact, you can call `myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)` multiple times.

@michaeljsalo : A very important thing to keep in mind is that since the return value of `myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)` is a DocumentFragment, adding event listeners on it will not work in the most cases. In case you need to add event listener consider using `myTemplate.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);`

@see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#avoiding_documentfragment_pitfall

Comment: @KossiD.T.S., you are responding to a year old comment, and the answer was updated back then. The original comment was about the version of the code that didn't call `cloneNode`, which was what Danny was referring to.

Comment: Okay... got it - sorry my bad ;)